# First time buyer help - Canon 800d or Nikon 5600

Tags: canon, nikon-d5600

I am planning to buy my first DSLR camera(only body) and currently I have finalised two models.

- Nikon 5600
- Canon 800d

Out of the two, I am more inclined towards canon 800d because of its user interface, auto focus and touch screen capabilities.

Along with the DSLR body, I planning to buy one sigma 18-35mm f1.8 lens and one telephoto lens. I don't want to go with the default kit lens(18-55mm) though its price is very less.

The main reason to go with sigma lens is to get good bokeh effect photos in low light conditions and avoid changing the lens for portrait Photography.

But i am not sure for regular photography the 35mm zoom will be sufficient and also the cost is shooting up if i add Telephoto lens.

Can you please advice how to get good dslr body with better lens for portrait and landscape shooting in a budget of 1800 AUD.

Comment: Nikon D5600 or D5500 has also a touch screen with wifi connectivity.

Answer (score 3):

> Can you please advice how to get good dslr body with better lens for portrait and landscape shooting in a budget of 1800 AUD

**Forget the Sigma 18-35mm. It's too much for the budget you have and everything else that you want.**

Get the 18-55mm kit lens (They're actually not that bad these days and they practically give them to you with the kit which is only about $150 more than body only) plus the EF 50mm f/1.8 STM instead. Even with an APS-C camera the 50mm is a more appropriate lens for most portrait styles than an 18-35mm would be. For a telephoto you can go with one of the EF-S 55-250mm varieties or an EF 85mm f/1.8 or EF 100mm f/2. You'll come out spending less on the 18-55mm + 50mm + 55-250mm than you would on the 18-35mm alone.

Note: I can't access any part of amazon in Australia other than the kindle store. So I can't see AUD prices but if they are similar to U.S. prices at the current USD to AUD exchange rate the 800D + 18-55mm kit lens + 55-250mm should come in at around 1,650 AUD. Add another 130-150 AUD for the 85mm or 100mm prime instead of the 55-250mm.

Comment: i have 50mm on my dx camera, its good for head & shoulder photos but the tight frame is really annoying, you have to go so far from subject if you want to get whole of a man in your frame! a little wider lens like nikkon 35mm f/1.8G will be better in my opinion

Comment: @S.Serp Perhaps, but those kind of full body and environmental portraits aren't usually the ones where a wide aperture, shallow DoF, and bokeh are a concern. Those are specifically mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> The main reason to go with sigma lens is to get good bokeh effect photos in low light conditions and avoid changing the lens for portrait Photography.

Be aware that to do this requires that you use a wide aperture and high ISO to try and get both a lot of out of focus blur and avoid motion blur by using a high shutter speed.

But also be aware that you probably won't avoid motion blur (a shot I took once comes to mind : ISO 3200, 1/60th and f1.4 which was in low light indoors and *still* had some motion blur).

It's a personal choice but I'd strongly advise you to get the kit lens (as Michael Clark suggested).  It's a useful lens and will allow you to get a feel for whether 18-35mm is a suitable range for your style of portrait photography on an APS-C sensor.  For me that would be a more or less useless range.  I'd typically start at 28mm and work up for portraits on APS-C.  My normal go-to lens for that is a 50mm f1.4 or f1.7 or f1.8 (I have five 50mm lenses as I find them so useful, ranging from old manual lenses to modern AF).

Also note that using a narrow aperture will means very small depth of field, making focus, already difficult to nail in low light, very challenging.  In low light AF will often be unreliable, with narrow DOF it's just asking for trouble.

I'd advise getting the kit lens and maybe a used 50mm f1.8 with any new or used DSLR made in the last five years.  You can get a different lens any time - there is no rush.

Answer (score 0):

I bow to the greater experience of the existing answers, but as a relative newcomer myself, let me perhaps wander down the "year of making your mind up & getting things wrong" in the hope that you perhaps make better choices than I did.

Firstly, Nikon or Canon... Most people seem to have Canon these days - but if you have friends with cameras, choose the same as they have - then you can share lenses.

I got the D5500 with the kit 18-55. I could either also get the Nikon 55-200mm or the Tamron 70-300. I went with the Tamron, for budget reasons & also for the extra 100mm.

That left me with a hole in the middle I filled with a Nikon 24-120.

I also got a nice 50mm 1.4 prime.

I now have a poor selection of lenses & need to consolidate.

As I never really seem to use the wider end of the scale, I'm going to sell the kit 18-55 and the 24-120 & fill the gap with something approximately 24-70 f2.8 ish. I'm looking at the Tokina which is going to hurt my wallet, but not as much as the Nikon would.

I'm avoiding DX lenses because eventually I will be looking at full frame & don't want to go through it all again.

Were I to be starting from scratch tomorrow - I'd have got the kit 18-55 & the 55-200, both DX, both relatively cheap & doesn't leave a hole in the middle.

From there, as you learn what you like to shoot, you can then pick out specialist lenses to cover those interest areas.

Comment: If you are looking for a good price/performance ratio in a 24-70/2.8 don't overlook the Tamron SP 24-70mm f/2.8 Di VC. It's a lot of lens for the current street price.